# Angular 7 - make keydown event on div not working

Tags: angular, keydown

I have angular 7 app with a search form. When typing into form, I'm filtering the output and present output as a list of div's. 
When using (click) event, I can select and trigger function, but when trying to use (keydown) event, it's not working.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="licensePlate" 
aria-describedby="licensePlate" 
name="licensePlate" #licensePlate="ngModel" 
required minlength="2" [(ngModel)]="carModel" [ngbTypeahead]="carAutoComplete" 
[inputFormatter]="CarFormatter" 
[resultTemplate]="carTemplate">
```

Working with mouse:

```html
<ng-template #carTemplate let-r="result" let-t="term">
    <div (click)="searchCar(r.id)">{{ r.licensePlate }} - {{ r.make }} {{ r.carModel }}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Not working with keyboard

```html
<ng-template #carTemplate let-r="result" let-t="term">
    <div (keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)" tabindex="0">{{ r.licensePlate }} - {{ r.make }} {{ r.carModel }}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Here's my TS code:

```js
carAutoComplete = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  text$.pipe(
    debounceTime(200),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
      : this.carsList.filter(v => v.licensePlate.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
  )
  CarFormatter = (x: {licensePlate: string}) => x.licensePlate;

  keyDownFunction(event) {
    console.log('Clicked keyboard:', event);
  }

  searchCar(id: number) {
    this.searchSelected = true;
    this.router.navigate(['car', id]);
  }
```

I want to be able to select a car with mouse and by keyboard only.

Comment: Can you post a minimal working demo on stackblitz

Answer (score 5):

In order to have the `keydown` event on elements such **div**, **p**, you must use the [contenteditable](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) attribute.

So you would have something like this:

```html
<ng-template #carTemplate let-r="result" let-t="term">
    <div contenteditable="true" (keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)" tabindex="0">{{ r.licensePlate }} - {{ r.make }} {{ r.carModel }}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, not ideal probably as requires 2 times Enter to be pressed (select div from list and then submit input, but at least works as expected.
Added keydown to input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="licensePlate" aria-describedby="licensePlate" name="licensePlate" #licensePlate="ngModel" 
required minlength="2" [(ngModel)]="carModel" 
[ngbTypeahead]="carAutoComplete" [inputFormatter]="CarFormatter" [resultTemplate]="carTemplate" 
(keydown)="searchCarKeyboard($event, licensePlate)">
```

And created new function:

```
searchCarKeyboard(event, licensePlate) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    if (licensePlate.model.id) {
      const carId = licensePlate.model.id;
      this.searchSelected = true;
      this.router.navigate(['car', carId]);
    }
  }
}
```